# Error compiling project with GWT

Tags: java, eclipse, gwt

I just did a checkout of a project with SVN,  and is showing me the following error.
I am really new using gwt and be very grateful if you could help me.

This is the error:

```
Loading inherited module 'com.google.web.bindery.event.Event'
[ERROR] Unable to find 'com/google/web/bindery/event/Event.gwt.xml' on your classpath; could be a 
a typo, or maybe you forgot to include a classpath entry for source?
[ERROR] Line 22: Unexpected exception while processing element 'inherits'
```

This is my xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module>

<!-- Inherit the core Web Toolkit stuff. -->
<inherits name="com.smartgwt.SmartGwt" />
<inherits name="com.smartgwt.tools.SmartGwtTools" />
<inherits name="com.google.gwt.activity.Activity" />
<inherits name="com.google.gwt.place.Place" />
<inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.User'/>


<inherits name="com.google.web.bindery.event.Event" /> 
<inherits name="com.google.gwt.core.Core" />
<entry-point class='ch.datalynx.clessidra.client.Clessidra' />
<inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.theme.standard.Standard'/>

<!-- <inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.theme.chrome.Chrome'/> -->
<!-- <inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.theme.dark.Dark'/> -->

<replace-with
    class="ch.datalynx.clessidra.client.mvp.clientfactories.ClientFactoryImpl">
    <when-type-is
        class="ch.datalynx.clessidra.client.mvp.clientfactories.ClientFactory" />
</replace-with>

<source path='client' />
<source path='shared' />

</module>
```

Comment: May be `GWT SDK` is not configured property in class path.

Comment: Which version of GWT are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the `gwt-user.jar` file is in your build path. It's part of the GWT SDK.

It is unable to find `gwt-user.jar/com/google/web/bindery/event/Event.gwt.xml`

Comment: Hi ! Thanks for answer yes it's in the build path, maybe you know an other reason that makes that error happens.

Comment: @user3430664 Check the "**Problems**" view of Eclipse to see if it says anything regarding your build path. And you have the GWT plugin and the SDK installed, right?